# Objective-C float string formatting: Formatting the whole numbers

Tags: objective-c

There are some great answers here about how to format the **decimal places** of a float for a string:

```
float myFloatA = 2.123456f;
NSLog(@"myFloatA: [%.2f]", myFloatA;
// returns:
// myFloatA: [2.12]
```

But what I'm looking for is how to format the **whole numbers** of the same float. This can be done with the same sort of trick on an integer:

```
int myInt = 2;
NSLog(@"myInt: [%5d]", myInt;
// returns:
// myInt: [    2]
```

So I was hoping something like a %5.2f would be the answer to formatting both before and after the decimal. But it doesn't:

```
float myFloatA = 2.123456f;
NSLog(@"myFloatA: [%5.2f]", myFloatA;
// returns:
// myFloatA: [2.12]
```

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: Can you test again? It works for me, see my post below.

Comment: What result do you want to get from: `NSLog(@"myFloatA: [%5.2f])", myFloatA;` for example?

Answer (score 1):

Using the print specifiers is all very well for NSLogs, but think about this another way.

Usually, you want a string representation of a number when you are displaying it in something like a text field. In which case, you might as well use an [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which does most of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also confirmed that this works. If you're worried you're not getting 5 character width, try forcing zero padding with:

```
NSLog(@"myFloatA: [%05.2f]", myFloatA);
```